# Get table name without schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a string that could be a table name with ANY schema, not necessarily dbo. How do I get the table name only from the string without knowing the schema? E.g. from 'dbo.MyTable' I would need to extract 'MyTable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used for this:

```
SELECT PARSENAME ('server.database.dbo.object', 1) -- object
SELECT PARSENAME ('database..object', 1)           -- object
SELECT PARSENAME ('object', 1)                     -- object
SELECT PARSENAME ('[foo bar]', 1)                  -- foo bar
```